# Deleting data from table synchronously using Room in android

Tags: android, android-room

I need to delete all data from tables synchronously and then insert the fresh data.

As per documentation @Query runs asynchronously so following method has not completed deleting data and we are starting inserting data in next line which is causing crash.

`@Query("DELETE FROM myTable")
    void deleteAll();`

Is there any way to delete it synchronously? should we change the return type of methods annotated with Query from void to int or should we use  RoomDatabase.clearAllTables() method. 
Not sure if void clearAllTables () also runs synchronously or not.

Comment: It's not room but android itself will not allow any task that blocks the UI. So everything needs to be done on background thread. By the way, why do you need to do it synchronously? No one likes their app to lag or hang!

Comment: We are already calling these operations in background thread. Room always does operations in the calling thread. As I said, we want to erase previous data before entering updated data

Comment: why are you trying achieve your goals in such a backwards manner? just fire another query to check if the data has been deleted or not and only insert when you're sure....

Comment: @KaranHarshWardhan how will you make sure that another query will return data synchronous? and then why should we make unnecessary IO operation to check if data has been deleted or not. Delete operation should itself be synchronous. Not understanding your modern manner :)

Comment: "As per documentation @Query runs asynchronously" -- only if you return a reactive type (e.g., `Single`, `LiveData`). Otherwise, it runs synchronously. "so following method has not completed deleting data and we are starting inserting data in next line which is causing crash" -- I suspect that there is some other problem here.

Comment: ok @CommonsWare I will check. Please let me know about RoomDatabase.clearAllTables() method as well. Does this operation runs synchronously. It might help to delete all tables in one call.

Comment: AFAIK, `clearAllTables()` runs synchronously. However, it clears *all* tables, whereas your `@Query` is only clearing one.

Comment: A code example of how are you deleting and inserting data would have been nice but you can try `executors.singleThread().submit(() -> roomDb.runInTransaction(() -> { /* clearAllTables() then insertData() */ }));`. Do it in a single transaction.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses

Comment: In room 2 you can just run query async with deleted items count as result. After that insert items.

Comment: @jczerski should be an answer instead of a comment, it's the proper solution

Answer (score 0):

In room 2 you can just run query async with deleted items count as result. After that insert items.

Answer (score 0):

if you call dao like

```java
someDao.deleteAll()
someDao.insert(someObj)
```

you haven't any guaranty that deleteAll will complete before start insert command. 
For make it in the chain just add in dao return parameter for deleteAll()

```
@Query("DELETE FROM table")
fun deleteAll(): Int
```

And now Room/SQLite will complete delete call for a return value to you.